# F# Iterate over N dimensions

Tags: recursion, f#, iteration, traversal

What is a good way of iterating over N dimensions in F#? Specifically I want to iterate the levels in a list of lists and display the different paths. Here's a trivial example of what I would like to do in arbitrary list dimensions.

```
let L1 = ["A"; "B"]
let L2 = ["C"; "D"]
let L3 = ["E"; "F"; "G"]

let pathSteps = [L1; L2; L3]

let printAllPaths =
    let allPaths =
        seq{
            for c1 in L1 do
                for c2 in L2 do
                    for c3 in L3 do
                         yield [c1; c2; c3] 
           }
    for ls in allPaths do
        ls
        |> Seq.toList
        |> printfn "%A"
```

Comment: How do you define best?

Comment: Good point. Most SO votes for the answer :) ?

Comment: In that case you will get closed as opinion based.

Comment: True - the answer on that SO question does the job.